# how to fill database with excel file upload

Tags: javascript, php, html

How can I fill my database table with excel by

```
form method = "post" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
<input type = "hidden" name = "upload" value = "1">
<input type = "file" name = "file">
<input type = "submit" value = "Upload"></form>
```

Comment: convert your excel into `CSV` format then try to upload it. here is noice tut http://www.webtutorialspoint.com/php/how-to-import-excel-file-into-mysql-database-table-using-php-code/

Comment: Thanks.....it helped a lot

Comment: welcome , glad to help